# CraftCMS Image Transform returning NULL on asset.url when stored on AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: craft3, image-transforms, graphql

So i'm using Craft as a headless CMS with a React frontend.

When querying assets on a S3 bucket and applying a transform to them in my GraphQL query the URL response is NULL.

This isn't the case when I apply the transform to assets on a local storage, and also isn't the case when I query the same asset stored on AWS S3 without the transform.

I checked my bucket and the subfolder isn't being generated with the transformed bucket so I assume because I'm triggering the transform through GraphQL and not a traditional template render it isn't generating the new image and storing it in AWS?

This is my graphQL query for the image, which was working when I was storing the file locally but since moving to S3 storage no longer works when the transform is applied:

```
blogImage @transform (handle:"blogthumbnail") {
    width
    height
    url
}
```

Response:

```
"blogImage": [
    {
        "width": 437,
        "height": 200,
        "url": null
    }
]
```

Any hints as to why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Comment: Getting the same issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Maybe this helps for others as well. My mistake was, that the filesystem setting in craft where the transformed files where generated to, didn't had the setting for public URLs active. When I activated public URLs I got URLs back from graphql.

[image]